# Neo4j: Join existing nodes in neo4j graph

Tags: neo4j, cypher, py2neo

Problem statement:
Add two input nodes n1 and n2 with edge directed n1-[:rel]->n2

```
1. if n1-[:rel]->n2 exists ignore
2. if n1 and n2 exists but not with [:rel]
   create a new relationship edge between the existing nodes
3. if n1 doesnt exist
   create n1 and join n1 and existing n2 with edge [:rel]
4. if n2 doesnt exist
   create n2 and join n2 and existing n1 with edge [:rel]
```

Query:

```
 INSERT_QUERY = ''' FOREACH(t IN {term_mod_pair_list}| 
    MERGE(tt:target_Word {type:'target_term',word:t[0]['word'],pos:t[0]['tag']})- 
    [:MODIFIER]->(mod:mod_Word {type:'a-mod',word:t[1]['word'],pos:t[0]['tag']}) ) '''
```

I find merge is creating duplicate nodes, after some finding i see merge matches exact pattern. 
so if `n1-[:rel]->n2` exist , new addition of relationship `n1-[:rel]->n3` 
will create another new node n1

I have explained my problem above. how can I achieve it.

Comment: Is this a homework/interview question? Also: You haven't shown any work. This isn't the place to post "problem statements" and have people write code for you.

Comment: Edit your question. Don't post a block of cypher in a comment. It's unreadable.

Comment: @DavidMakogon can you see it now

Comment: You aren't using merge correctly. See my answer. You need to merge on the individual parts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will cover all four points with the additional point of:

If n1 and n2 don't exist, create n1 and n2 and join with edge [:rel].

```
MERGE (n1:Label {unique_prop: "unique_value"})
MERGE (n2:Label {unique_prop: "unique_value"})
MERGE (n1)-[:rel]->(n2);
```